# What should I replace "test_images" and "test_labels" with inside this Convolutional Neural Network Machine Learning Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

What should I replace "test_images" and "test_labels" with inside this Convolutional Neural Network Machine Learning Model?

I trained my model and saved it using this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K


# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = 'data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
nb_train_samples = 4000
nb_validation_samples = 800
epochs = 50
batch_size = 18

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save_weights('first_try.h5')
# Saving Model
model.save("modeln1.tf")
```

After that, I decided to load my model and print out its summary and accuracy using this code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import os

new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/Users/test/Documents/DigiDoctorTF/modeln1.tf')

new_model.summary()

loss, acc = new_model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, verbose=2)

print('Accuracy: {:5.2f}%'.format(100*acc))
```

I tried this with both the model and the weights file. However, I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ld1.py", line 9, in <module>
    loss, acc = new_model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, verbose=2)
NameError: name 'test_images' is not defined
```

What is this error?  What do I replace test_images with?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ld1.py", line 9, in <module>
    loss, acc = new_model.evaluate(train_generator, validation_generator, verbose=2)
NameError: name 'test_images' is not defined
```

The variable 'test_images' is not defined. What is test_images? How would computer know that. Define the variable (store images array in it) and then run it.

Edit 1 - test_labels is also not defined, define the labels too and then run it.

Comment: I agree, the test_images and labels are the arrays. I got my info from this: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load. However, I am still unsure what to do. Can I get a *sample code*

Answer (score 0):

try assigning a file path for the image you want to classify to test_images.
like the following:

```
test_images = 'C:/Users/test/Documents/DigiDoctorTF/image1.jpg'
```

you might need to using something like pytorch to set classify the filepath as a directory or maybe use built in python os dir commands.